How to render a specific page on Server Side in Blazor Web Application?
I have created a blazor web application by selecting Auto Interactive Render Mode and Global Interactivity location. So the solution has the routes and layout in client project. Now I want to render a blogDetail page on server side for better SEO. I already have the page on client project which is using httpClient to get data from server project's api.
How can I make the page render at server side initially without breaking the page's interactivity?

You could create a repo interface that is common across both. ServerSomeRepo : ISomeRepo and ClientSomeRepo : ISomeRepo. Then inject by interface. .AddTransient<ISomeRepo, ServerSomeRepo> and .AddScoped<ISomeRepo, ClientSomeRepo>in their respective program.cs files. Place the interface in the client project as the server includes this as a library. The server repo could use the dbContext directly without the need for a httpClient. Your controller may/should already have a repo injected into it...

I think you could dynamically set global rendermode. Try modify like following in the "App.razor":
...
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
...
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
...
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;
    
//when the route is "blogDetail ", set to InteractiveServer(disable prerender SSR)
    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/blogDetail")
        ? new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false)
        : InteractiveAuto;
}


Doesnt work unfortunately
